# Make a partialview into html "string" in my controller, for json request

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm making a jQuery JSON post and want to return a PartialView as HTML. In my controller I need to make the PartialView into HTML.

I found some examples, but most of them involve a BaseController. My project does not allow me to use a BaseController. I would rather need an extension that I could use in the controller instead.

I looked at some code and found an example, but I'm having some problems with using it. I don't know how to pass in the current controller I use.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult HtmlJsonTryout(/*passing values*/)
{
    //code here......
    if (first.CartID == 0)
    {               
        var viewData = m_cartViewDataFactory.Create();
        var miniCart = ControllerExtensionsHelper.PartialViewToString("HERE I NEED TO PASS CONTROLLER RIGHT?", "_FullCart", viewData);
        var cart = PartialView("_CartSum", viewData);

        this.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        return Json(new
        {
            Status = "OK",
            MiniCart = miniCart,
            Cart = cart
        });
    }
}

public static class ControllerExtensionsHelper
{
    public static string PartialViewToString(this Controller controller)
    {
        return controller.PartialViewToString(null, null);
    }

    public static string RenderPartialViewToString(this Controller controller, string viewName)
    {
        return controller.PartialViewToString(viewName, null);
    }

    public static string RenderPartialViewToString(this Controller controller, object model)
    {
        return controller.PartialViewToString(null, model);
    }

    public static string PartialViewToString(this Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        {
            viewName = controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
        }

        controller.ViewData.Model = model;

        using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, stringWriter);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, stringWriter);
            return stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the extension method correctly. You invoke extension methods on an instance of the class they are extending. Please read the documentation about [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult HtmlJsonTryout(int amount)
{
    if (first.CartID == 0)
    {               
        var viewData = m_cartViewDataFactory.Create();
        string miniCart = this.PartialViewToString("_FullCart", viewData);
        string cart = this.PartialViewToString("_CartSum", viewData);

        return Json(new
        {
            Status = "OK",
            MiniCart = miniCart,
            Cart = cart
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: i have read the part "Binding Extension Methods at Compile Time" because that is the error im getting when trying to do like you did in the example with `this.PartialViewToString()`. any ideas on why?

Comment: Error: Constant initializer must be compile-time constant. I found that only `strings` and `ints` are comple-time constants so how can i apply this to a controller?

Comment: The code works for me. There must be something else you are doing wrong. On which line (of my example) are you getting this error?

Comment: Works, nevermind. I had a `const string` that i missed to remove. Thanks Darin :)